# Poi-ooxml-schema source or jar for document only

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am doing the document conversion using the poi.

For that i am using poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar which is contains sheet and powerpoint classes and beans. I want separate the document classes and bean.

There is no source for poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9 so that I can't separate the package and beans.

How to generate the build.xml or any source for generate the document classes and beans?

Simply I want generate the poi-ooxml-schema as my wish.

Answer (score 3):

There *is* source available for the ooxml schemas! It's [covered in the POI FAQ](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10109)

The schema classes are auto-generated by xmlbeans from the specification, but you can get the auto-generated sources if you want. Depending on your needs, you can either use the ant build file to generate them, or download the pre-generated ones from Maven central. The [FAQ covers both options](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10109)

Comment: Basically saying you can use version 5 of poi-ooxml-full directly from Maven: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/poi-ooxml-full/5.0.0/poi-ooxml-full-5.0.0-sources.jar